# How to implement REST API that supports SCIM filtering in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, scim

I need to implement an ASP.NET Web API that supports querying users as SCIM filtering specs https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.4.2.2.

What is the fastest way to do that? I know that I need to implement a parser that can parse filtering expression, then execute that expression with the dedicated user repository and return selected entities, but that is a huge work to implement that parser from the scratch, right?

Is there any faster way or more standard way to support SCIM filtering?

Comment: your best bet currently if you don't have time to create parser for yourself is this http://beyond-code.com/LinqToQuerystring/syntax.html
the problem is that this library wasn't updated for more than 2 years...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see https://github.com/PowerDMS/Owin.Scim

I have implemented it such that Owin.Scim takes the filter string, whether a query filter or patch filter, normalizes it, and then constructs an expression tree / lambda predicate which you can use in linq.

What's not yet implemented is how to support SCIM's query-on-root - where you're filtering on multiple resource types at once.

`ScimFilter` normalizes the string with support for resource extensions.
Patching is a whole separate process which uses a custom json.net contract resolver. At the time of this writing, ScimFilter will give you a list of PathFilterExpressions. (if you're querying, you'll only have one).

You can use an extension method to take a `PathFilterExpression` and get back a strongly-typed predicate (`Func<Resource, bool>`). See: https://github.com/PowerDMS/Owin.Scim/blob/master/source/Owin.Scim/Extensions/PathFilterExpressionExtensions.cs

Alternatively, you can grab the alpha Owin.Scim.Antlr dll.  https://github.com/PowerDMS/Owin.Scim/tree/master/source/lib

This will give you the `ScimFilterLexer` & `ScimFilterParser`.

Comment: I should note that this project is still in alpha so bugs may and probably do exist

Comment: It works great. Thank you a lot. You saved my day. I still need to implement some more custom eq, gt, lt..operator for double, Uri..but anyway, it's fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I've written a considerable amount of tests to cover scim filters in owin.scim but if you find any issues, please feel free to report them as github issues. Also, please mark this as the answer on here if you end up going with it. Thanks!